# I want to create custom route for my Laravel 7 project

Tags: routes, laravel-7

I have tried to define a custom route for my Laravel 7 project, it didn't work and didn't redirect to the desired controller

My route is a follows:

```
Route::resource('abc/abc-damages','AbcDamagesController');
```

The real scenario is I have a controller it calls `Housing`, when I call `/housing` without problem it loads. I also have another controller `HousinItem` and I want it to call as `housing/house-items`. The problem is it returns empty view.

My router is:

```
Route::resource('/housing/house-items','HousinItemController');
```

Comment: Did you run php artisan optimize after you edited your routes file to get it to pick up any changes?

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` to see if your routes are there. Make sure your routes are not cached (you never want to cache in development): `php artisan route:clear`.  Is your controller correctly named, class name correct, in the right directory?

Comment: I tried to run php artisan optimize & php artisan route:list commands, router errors come.

Comment: What does "*router errors come*" mean?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  
LogicException
Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

Comment: That means you have a closure route, [like this one](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing), which cannot be cached. That's OK, you **don't** want to cache it. 1) Run `php artisan route:clear` 2) Run `php artisan route:list`  Are your routes there?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes can see the route but view doesnt load.

Comment: Now that you have clarified the real issue, the problem is clear. Laravel processes routes in your route files from top to bottom. If a URL matches more than 1 route,  the first one in the file will be used. A resource route for `/housing` defines several routes like `/housing/{house}`, where `{house}` is a wildcard that will match anything.  You can see the problem - `/housing/house-items` also matches that route. If your `/housing` resource route appears first in your routes file, the `Housing` Controller will be used, even for `/housing/house-items`.

Comment: There are a few options: 1) don't "nest" your routes, keep them separate, eg `/housing`, and `/house-items`.  2) If the parameters after the root of the URL are different between the 2, you can use a [regular expression to constrain the `{wildcard}`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Comment: @Don'tPanic I put the route before /housing  It works, thank you very my, highly appreciated.